# Laravel 9 Verify Email Address URL

Tags: laravel, email

Laravel 9 sends a custom mail to newly created user.

`Mail::to($request->email)->send(new NewCompany($data));`

How to get the URL which verifies email and store it in $data?

Standard email verification works fine, but I must use this feature also in another case.

I have found out something like this, but do not know how to adopt it to my own controller.

```
VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function (object $notifiable, string $url) {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Verify Email Address')
            ->line('Click the button below to verify your email address.')
            ->action('Verify Email Address', $url);
    });
```